# Using Visual Studios 2019 causes 100% Disk Usage

Tags: visual-studio

I've created an account on this site just for this explicit problem, a while back when I was coding scripts on unity I found that using visual studios, even **opening** visual studios will send my disk usage into the ceiling 100% for VS2019 after some time VS2019 seems to "give" all its disk usage to another service like system sysmain or a malware service honestly its fairly random but the 2 highest are systems and sysmain. after some time systems will completely take over and use 100% disk for as long as the VS2019 is open, if I close the program my laptop takes about 3-10min to return back to normal. I've looked all over to see if there was a solution but it seems I'm the only 1 suffering from this problem. Some feedback would be really lovely hoping a solution can be found before my next semester starts in mid-January.

Sincerely, Daniel Joseph Jr.

Comment: Just to clarify, by "100% disk usage" you mean it consumes all of the available I/O bandwidth to the disk, not that it fills the disk leaving zero free bytes, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are available I/O bandwidth on task manager I just see VS2019 or some other service at 100% and it freezes my entire computer for minutes. It all stops after i close VS2019

Comment: Sorry about the wording of the previous comments to clarify I don't know where to get information about the bandwidth I/O

Comment: In `Task Manager` on the `Performance` tab you can click on `Resource Monitor...`. Resource Monitor will let you explore CPU, memory, disk and network usage by process.